# Getting files from an external partition

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

So I had an external partition on Windows where I used to save (Not important stuff) stuff. Whatever I've been looking around but there's no tool that let's you check the partition.

Is there any tool that lets you look the stuff inside a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a window. Underneath the buttons that let you close the window, there should be a list labelled "Devices". Your Windows partition should be there. It might be named after the size of the partition.

Comment: The partition didn't have Windows, not listed, though

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't accidentally remove it?

Comment: Well, maybe i did. Didn't have anything important now. Whatever, i've made another partition but still it doesn't appear under Devices. It's mounted on a folder. Is that alright?

Comment: Have you tried using Disk Utility? It might be there, but unmounted.

Comment: It appears as "Mounted", I've set it to a folder called part2. But doesn't appear under Devices. Only appears the folder in where Ubuntu is installed.